# How can i read an array from firebase 9 using react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to read the array in the firebase
firebase array format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liAkn.png)

and store it in a one similar to Chart_data
I want it in this format [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMPJ0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is how I usually do it from Firestore. I don't know what storage structure you're using in your database but I'll assume you've got a collection of users, then a collection of charts.

If not, just adjust it accordingly.

Imports:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../../../../firebaseConfig"; // path to your firebaseConfig file
```

Code, paste inside functional component

```
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);

    // a reference to the chart you want
    const chartReference = doc(db, "dashboard_analytics", "E8V0JbotwbK9TqgtMSXF");

    // used to fetch the data from your firestore database
    const fetchChartData = async () => {
        // attempts to fetch data for the referenced chart
        const documentSnapshot = await getDoc(chartReference);

        let docChartData = [];

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
            // the name of the field of the array
            docChartData = docSnap.data().ordersGraph;
        } else {
            // The document doesn't exist
            console.log("No such document!");
        }

        // stores ordersGraph array into the state variable, chartData
        setChartData([...docChartData]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // calls the function on the load of the page
        fetchChartData();
    }, []);
```

You can then access it by using the chartData state variable.

Comment: i added the images, can you check now

Comment: Just changed it to match the images, should work now. If this helped can you please click the tick to accept my answer?